# dumpcap stops logging after 1184 files?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Recently I come across a linux application design. The indent of the application is to log the ethernet frames via dumpcap <> api in linux. But they implemented as below:

1. Create a new process using fork()
2. Call dumpcap <> in execl() as shown below

   a.    `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", dumpcap<>, NULL);`

   b.    `sudo dumpcap -i "eth0" -B 1 -b filesize:5 -w "/mnt/Test_1561890567.pcapng" -t -q`
3. They send a SIGTERM to kill the process

The problem facing now is when ever we run the command from the process after 1184 or 1185 no:files then dumpcap stops logging. The process and thread is alive the command we can see in top command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of using an enumerated list as you have here.

Comment: The issue i am facing is only happens if i try to create file more than 1184 via c program and also if i try to run it in terminal also it is stopped after certain number now i not remembering the number properly but it stopped logging. My concern is there any limitation in dumpcap in file creation...

Comment: i am running command in raspbian